# AMP Website/URL showing blank page

Tags: wordpress, web, amp-html

I'm trying to implement AMP on my wordpress website but even though it is validated when I access the link the page is "blank". Just has a title and a link to view the non AMP version. I can't find the problem. The link is:

https://www.maracajaukitecenter.com/amp/

I checked another topic here about that same issue but I don't have the same problem on my code. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any wordpress plugin?? It looks like your wordpress has a static page you should check the configuration to set the static page in the amp version.

Comment: Yes I have few plugins. But messing here in the settings with the static page idea in mind it seems to have worked. Now I just need to tweak the design. Thanks for the Help!

Comment: Or not, now it's not showing blank, but still missing a lot, like the menu. Ill play around and see if I can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your wordpress has a static page you should check the configuration to set the static page in the amp version.